# ReactJS pagination error "Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined"

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, pagination, react-bootstrap-table

```
var environmentList=this.state.returnJSONValue;
console.log("result for: environmentList hi :"+this.state.returnJSONValue);

return (
    <div>
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col-lg-12">
                <h3 className="page-header">
                    Docker Images
                </h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                   {environmentList}
            </div>
        </div>

        <BootstrapTable data={environmentList} striped hover pagination>
            <TableHeaderColumn isKey dataField='id'>#</TableHeaderColumn>
            <TableHeaderColumn dataField='name'>Environment</TableHeaderColumn>
            <TableHeaderColumn dataField='price'>Deploy</TableHeaderColumn>
        </BootstrapTable>

    </div>
)
```

I am using above code to create a table with react bootstrap  and want to implement pagination on the table but i am getting the following error.Kindly let me know if any solution:

```
index.js:56493 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined
    at new BootstrapTable (index.js:56493)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (index.js:14894)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.wrapper [as mountComponent] (index.js:9084)
    at Object.mountComponent (index.js:13276)
    at ReactDOMComponent.mountChildren (index.js:21846)
    at ReactDOMComponent._createContentMarkup (index.js:19021)
    at ReactDOMComponent.mountComponent (index.js:18909)
    at Object.mountComponent (index.js:13276)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (index.js:14971)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.wrapper [as mountComponent] (index.js:9084)
```

Answer (score 1):

Changes:

**1-** `React Bootstrap table` accept `array of object` in data property, that should contain the keys u defined in `dataField` in `TableHeaderColumn`. In you case `environmentList` should be like this:

```
[
  {id:1, name: 'A', price: 1},
  {id:2, name: 'B', price: 2}, 
  {id:3, name: 'C', price: 3}
]
```

**2-** Since your `environmentList` is an array, you can't render it directly in `html` like this: `{environmentList}`, you need to render the specific property like this: `{environmentList[0].name}`.

**3-** Your `environmentList` should not be `undefined` or `null`, otherwise table will throw error, to ensure that use it `environmentList || []`,

```
<BootstrapTable data={environmentList || []} striped hover pagination>
    <TableHeaderColumn isKey={true} dataField='id'>#</TableHeaderColumn>
    <TableHeaderColumn dataField='name'>Environment</TableHeaderColumn
    <TableHeaderColumn dataField='price'>Deploy</TableHeaderColumn>
</BootstrapTable>
```

I think you are getting the `error` because of that only, if your `environmentList` would have been proper then `JSX` would have thrown error of `render an array in html`.

Make the change it should work.

Comment: my environmentList is JSON that i m fetching from an API call

Comment: so basically this dataField=" " which i will give , will in a way map to the column of the array

Comment: but what if the JSON has only one column and i want other two columns to be a serial order or some action. ?

Comment: not a problem if json has only one column, you can use the other column for some action. could you show ur json?? u r problem get resolved or still facing ??

Comment: ["nginx_consul","progrium/consul","reactjs/servercode","redis","redisabi","redisabi_latest","restdemo","restdemoabi","sken/gitbucket","spotify/kafka","tomcat"] this is my json.I need one column of table as serial number, second column i want to iterate these and in third i want a button for some action.

Comment: still facing, it gives this error :  Invalid prop `data` supplied to `BootstrapTable`. Check the render method

Comment: ur json is not proper it should be, use this: [ 
 {id:1, name:"nginx_consul"},
 {id:2, name:"progrium/consul"},
 {id:3, name:"reactjs/servercode"},
 {id:4, name:"redi‌​s"},
 {id:5, name:"redisabi"},
 {id:6, name:"redis‌​abi_latest"},
 {id:7, name:"restdem‌​o"},
 {id:8, name:"restdemoabi"},
 {id:9, name:"sk‌​en/gitbucket"},
 {id:10, name:"spoti‌​fy/kafka"},
 {id:11, name:"tomcat"}
]
and for third column use dataFormatter and return a action button.